# API REST devuelve string convertir json

Tags: json, api, string, null

Estoy consultando la API de la aemet.
Al hacer la consulta me devuelve un string(json), que al intentar convertirlo a array me devuelve null.

Si le hago un var_dump, y el contenido lo paso a una variable, y de ahí lo convierto a array, va todo perfecto.

No entiendo qué estoy haciendo mal.

Muchas gracias por adelantado por vuestra ayuda

Os pongo el código:

```
$url = "https://opendata.aemet.es/opendata/sh/76b7b0ec";
$temp = file_get_contents($url);
$result = json_decode($temp,true);
var_dump($result);
```

El resultado, como decía, es:
NULL

Adjunto el contenido de $temp usando var_dump:

```
string(13637) "[ { "origen" : { "productor" : "Agencia Estatal de Meteorolog�a - AEMET. Gobierno de Espa�a", "web" : "https://www.aemet.es", "enlace" : "https://www.aemet.es/es/eltiempo/prediccion/municipios/tarragona-id43148", "language" : "es", "copyright" : "� AEMET. Autorizado el uso de la informaci�n y su reproducci�n citando a AEMET como autora de la misma.", "notaLegal" : "https://www.aemet.es/es/nota_legal" }, "elaborado" : "2021-12-31T07:16:11", "nombre" : "Tarragona", "provincia" : "Tarragona", "prediccion" : { "dia" : [ { "probPrecipitacion" : [ { "value" : 0, "periodo" : "00-24" }, { "value" : 0, "periodo" : "00-12" }, { "value" : 0, "periodo" : "12-24" }, { "value" : 0, "periodo" : "00-06" }, { "value" : 0, "periodo" : "06-12" }, { "value" : 0, "periodo" : "12-18" }, { "value" : 0, "periodo" : "18-24" } ], "cotaNieveProv" : [ { "value" : "", "periodo" : "00-24" }, { "value" : "", "periodo" : "00-12" }, { "value" : "", "periodo" : "12-24" }, { "value" : "", "periodo" : "00-06" }, { "value" : "", "periodo" : "06-12" }, { "value" : "", "periodo" : "12-18" }, { "value" : "", "periodo" : "18-24" } ], "estadoCielo" : [ { "value" : "17", "periodo" : "00-24", "descripcion" : "Nubes altas" }, { "value" : "12", "periodo" : "00-12", "descripcion" : "Poco nuboso" }, { "value" : "14", "periodo" : "12-24", "descripcion" : "Nuboso" }, { "value" : "12n", "periodo" : "00-06", "descripcion" : "Poco nuboso" }, { "value" : "12", "periodo" : "06-12", "descripcion" : "Poco nuboso" }, { "value" : "81", "periodo" : "12-18", "descripcion" : "Niebla " }, { "value" : "81n", "periodo" : "18-24", "descripcion" : "Niebla " } ], "viento" : [ { "direccion" : "C", "velocidad" : 0, "periodo" : "00-24" }, { "direccion" : "NE", "velocidad" : 10, "periodo" : "00-12" }, { "direccion" : "E", "velocidad" : 5, "periodo" : "12-24" }, { "direccion" : "NE", "velocidad" : 10, "periodo" : "00-06" }, { "direccion" : "C", "velocidad" : 0, "periodo" : "06-12" }, { "direccion" : "E", "velocidad" : 5, "periodo" : "12-18" }, { "direccion" : "C", "velocidad" : 0, "periodo" : "18-24" } ], "rachaMax" : [ { "value" : "", "periodo" : "00-24" }, { "value" : "", "periodo" : "00-12" }, { "value" : "", "periodo" : "12-24" }, { "value" : "", "periodo" : "00-06" }, { "value" : "", "periodo" : "06-12" }, { "value" : "", "periodo" : "12-18" }, { "value" : "", "periodo" : "18-24" } ], "temperatura" : { "maxima" : 18, "minima" : 9, "dato" : [ { "value" : 11, "hora" : 6 }, { "value" : 17, "hora" : 12 }, { "value" : 13, "hora" : 18 }, { "value" : 12, "hora" : 24 } ] }, "sensTermica" : { "maxima" : 18, "minima" : 10, "dato" : [ { "value" : 11, "hora" : 6 }, { "value" : 17, "hora" : 12 }, { "value" : 13, "hora" : 18 }, { "value" : 12, "hora" : 24 } ] }, "humedadRelativa" : { "maxima" : 90, "minima" : 50, "dato" : [ { "value" : 75, "hora" : 6 }, { "value" : 50, "hora" : 12 }, { "value" : 85, "hora" : 18 }, { "value" : 85, "hora" : 24 } ] }, "uvMax" : 1, "fecha" : "2021-12-31T00:00:00" }, { "probPrecipitacion" : [ { "value" : 0, "periodo" : "00-24" }, { "value" : 0, "periodo" : "00-12" }, { "value" : 0, "periodo" : "12-24" }, { "value" : 0, "periodo" : "00-06" }, { "value" : 0, "periodo" : "06-12" }, { "value" : 0, "periodo" : "12-18" }, { "value" : 0, "periodo" : "18-24" } ], "cotaNieveProv" : [ { "value" : "", "periodo" : "00-24" }, { "value" : "", "periodo" : "00-12" }, { "value" : "", "periodo" : "12-24" }, { "value" : "", "periodo" : "00-06" }, { "value" : "", "periodo" : "06-12" }, { "value" : "", "periodo" : "12-18" }, { "value" : "", "periodo" : "18-24" } ], "estadoCielo" : [ { "value" : "12", "periodo" : "00-24", "descripcion" : "Poco nuboso" }, { "value" : "14", "periodo" : "00-12", "descripcion" : "Nuboso" }, { "value" : "11", "periodo" : "12-24", "descripcion" : "Despejado" }, { "value" : "81n", "periodo" : "00-06", "descripcion" : "Niebla " }, { "value" : "14", "periodo" : "06-12", "descripcion" : "Nuboso" }, { "value" : "11", "periodo" : "12-18", "descripcion" : "Despejado" }, { "value" : "12n", "periodo" : "18-24", "descripcion" : "Poco nuboso" } ], "viento" : [ { "direccion" : "C", "velocidad" : 0, "periodo" : "00-24" }, { "direccion" : "C", "velocidad" : 0, "periodo" : "00-12" }, { "direccion" : "C", "velocidad" : 0, "periodo" : "12-24" }, { "direccion" : "C", "velocidad" : 0, "periodo" : "00-06" }, { "direccion" : "C", "velocidad" : 0, "periodo" : "06-12" }, { "direccion" : "C", "velocidad" : 0, "periodo" : "12-18" }, { "direccion" : "NE", "velocidad" : 10, "periodo" : "18-24" } ], "rachaMax" : [ { "value" : "", "periodo" : "00-24" }, { "value" : "", "periodo" : "00-12" }, { "value" : "", "periodo" : "12-24" }, { "value" : "", "periodo" : "00-06" }, { "value" : "", "periodo" : "06-12" }, { "value" : "", "periodo" : "12-18" }, { "value" : "", "periodo" : "18-24" } ], "temperatura" : { "maxima" : 22, "minima" : 8, "dato" : [ { "value" : 11, "hora" : 6 }, { "value" : 20, "hora" : 12 }, { "value" : 14, "hora" : 18 }, { "value" : 10, "hora" : 24 } ] }, "sensTermica" : { "maxima" : 21, "minima" : 7, "dato" : [ { "value" : 11, "hora" : 6 }, { "value" : 20, "hora" : 12 }, { "value" : 14, "hora" : 18 }, { "value" : 10, "hora" : 24 } ] }, "humedadRelativa" : { "maxima" : 100, "minima" : 45, "dato" : [ { "value" : 90, "hora" : 6 }, { "value" : 45, "hora" : 12 }, { "value" : 70, "hora" : 18 }, { "value" : 50, "hora" : 24 } ] }, "uvMax" : 1, "fecha" : "2022-01-01T00:00:00" }, { "probPrecipitacion" : [ { "value" : 0, "periodo" : "00-24" }, { "value" : 0, "periodo" : "00-12" }, { "value" : 0, "periodo" : "12-24" } ], "cotaNieveProv" : [ { "value" : "", "periodo" : "00-24" }, { "value" : "", "periodo" : "00-12" }, { "value" : "", "periodo" : "12-24" } ], "estadoCielo" : [ { "value" : "17", "periodo" : "00-24", "descripcion" : "Nubes altas" }, { "value" : "17", "periodo" : "00-12", "descripcion" : "Nubes altas" }, { "value" : "17", "periodo" : "12-24", "descripcion" : "Nubes altas" } ], "viento" : [ { "direccion" : "SE", "velocidad" : 10, "periodo" : "00-24" }, { "direccion" : "NE", "velocidad" : 10, "periodo" : "00-12" }, { "direccion" : "SE", "velocidad" : 10, "periodo" : "12-24" } ], "rachaMax" : [ { "value" : "", "periodo" : "00-24" }, { "value" : "", "periodo" : "00-12" }, { "value" : "", "periodo" : "12-24" } ], "temperatura" : { "maxima" : 19, "minima" : 8, "dato" : [ ] }, "sensTermica" : { "maxima" : 19, "minima" : 8, "dato" : [ ] }, "humedadRelativa" : { "maxima" : 80, "minima" : 50, "dato" : [ ] }, "uvMax" : 1, "fecha" : "2022-01-02T00:00:00" }, { "probPrecipitacion" : [ { "value" : 0, "periodo" : "00-24" }, { "value" : 0, "periodo" : "00-12" }, { "value" : 0, "periodo" : "12-24" } ], "cotaNieveProv" : [ { "value" : "", "periodo" : "00-24" }, { "value" : "", "periodo" : "00-12" }, { "value" : "", "periodo" : "12-24" } ], "estadoCielo" : [ { "value" : "12", "periodo" : "00-24", "descripcion" : "Poco nuboso" }, { "value" : "12", "periodo" : "00-12", "descripcion" : "Poco nuboso" }, { "value" : "12", "periodo" : "12-24", "descripcion" : "Poco nuboso" } ], "viento" : [ { "direccion" : "S", "velocidad" : 5, "periodo" : "00-24" }, { "direccion" : "S", "velocidad" : 5, "periodo" : "00-12" }, { "direccion" : "O", "velocidad" : 5, "periodo" : "12-24" } ], "rachaMax" : [ { "value" : "", "periodo" : "00-24" }, { "value" : "", "periodo" : "00-12" }, { "value" : "", "periodo" : "12-24" } ], "temperatura" : { "maxima" : 19, "minima" : 9, "dato" : [ ] }, "sensTermica" : { "maxima" : 19, "minima" : 9, "dato" : [ ] }, "humedadRelativa" : { "maxima" : 85, "minima" : 50, "dato" : [ ] }, "uvMax" : 1, "fecha" : "2022-01-03T00:00:00" }, { "probPrecipitacion" : [ { "value" : 5 } ], "cotaNieveProv" : [ { "value" : "" } ], "estadoCielo" : [ { "value" : "12", "descripcion" : "Poco nuboso" } ], "viento" : [ { "direccion" : "O", "velocidad" : 10 } ], "rachaMax" : [ { "value" : "" } ], "temperatura" : { "maxima" : 22, "minima" : 9, "dato" : [ ] }, "sensTermica" : { "maxima" : 22, "minima" : 9, "dato" : [ ] }, "humedadRelativa" : { "maxima" : 80, "minima" : 40, "dato" : [ ] }, "uvMax" : 1, "fecha" : "2022-01-04T00:00:00" }, { "probPrecipitacion" : [ { "value" : 15 } ], "cotaNieveProv" : [ { "value" : "1400" } ], "estadoCielo" : [ { "value" : "14", "descripcion" : "Nuboso" } ], "viento" : [ { "direccion" : "C", "velocidad" : 0 } ], "rachaMax" : [ { "value" : "" } ], "temperatura" : { "maxima" : 18, "minima" : 8, "dato" : [ ] }, "sensTermica" : { "maxima" : 18, "minima" : 8, "dato" : [ ] }, "humedadRelativa" : { "maxima" : 90, "minima" : 50, "dato" : [ ] }, "fecha" : "2022-01-05T00:00:00" }, { "probPrecipitacion" : [ { "value" : 5 } ], "cotaNieveProv" : [ { "value" : "" } ], "estadoCielo" : [ { "value" : "12", "descripcion" : "Poco nuboso" } ], "viento" : [ { "direccion" : "C", "velocidad" : 0 } ], "rachaMax" : [ { "value" : "" } ], "temperatura" : { "maxima" : 16, "minima" : 7, "dato" : [ ] }, "sensTermica" : { "maxima" : 16, "minima" : 7, "dato" : [ ] }, "humedadRelativa" : { "maxima" : 100, "minima" : 75, "dato" : [ ] }, "fecha" : "2022-01-06T00:00:00" } ] }, "id" : -22388, "version" : 1.0 } ]"
```

Comment: No puedo probarlo insitu, porque me devuelve datos expirados, pero copiando tu string devuelto y asignandolo a una variable $temp en su lugar, si que me hace la conversión a matriz correctamente

Comment: En caso de que la respuesta de la api sea un json, el codigo yo lo veo perfecto. No deberia fallar algo tan simple como eso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He tenido que darme de alta en aemet.es para solucionar este caso, pero ha valido la pena.

El problema es básicamente la **codificación de carácteres** devueltos, que esta en `Windows-1252`.

Para solucionarlo hay que convertirlos a UTF-8 **antes** del `json_decode`.

Para ello a mi me ha funcionado con:

```
$temp = mb_convert_encoding($temp, 'UTF8', 'Windows-1252');
```

Prueba y confirma que te funciona.

La función [mb_convert_encoding](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) realiza una conversión de codificación de caracteres, en este caso desde [windows-1252](/questions/tagged/windows-1252) a [utf-8](/questions/tagged/utf-8).

Comment: PERFECTO, esto lo arregla perfectamente. Estoy alucinado, con la de tiempo que he perdido para ésto.

Por cierto, cómo has descubierto el tipo de codificación?

Comment: @PedroCerrato: Pues apuntandome a la web de aemet, reproducciendo tu descarga con mi API key, guardandola en archivo, y abriendolo con el editor Sublime y mirando la codificación en su barra inferior.

Comment: Por cierto, que mal educado soy, MIL GRACIAS  a todos por responser y por el esfuerzo de "masterguru" por registrarse y por explicarlo tan bien.

Comment: De nada, soy muy curioso y me gustan los retos :-)  Y aparte de todo eso me gusta ayudar y todo por el bien de la comunidad, claro

Comment: Por cierto, cómo has podido saber que la codificación es: Windows-1252 ??

Comment: @PedroCerrato Te lo he dicho en otro comentario un poco mas arriba, con el Sublime (editor de texto)

Comment: Buenos días.
Teías toda la razón lo ví en el comentario de más arriba.
Probé también la conversión de la siguiente forma:
mb_convert_encoding($temp, 'UTF8');
Y también funcionó.
De nuevo muchas gracias